# Adding a custom rule in the <xsd:simpleType> element for a validation of a special case

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, simpletype

I have an XML file with the element tag **product_long_description**, the XML will be validated via **xsd**

**product_long_description**  can have some text which I want to have max  4000 characters, **product_long_description** also has a few  **line break**  tags but while validating for max **4000**
characters, I want to ignore all the **line break**  for the character count

- Snippet of the **XML**

  ```
    <product_long_description>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet<br> consectetur adipisicing <br>elit. Reprehenderit, sed.</product_long_description>
  ```

> While checking for character limit, I want to skip those **line break**  text for
> the character count

- Snippet of the **xsd**

```
<xsd:element name="product_long_description" type="TextType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Long Description of Product</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>



<xsd:simpleType name="TextType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:minLength value="0"/>
        <xsd:maxLength value="4000"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

I tried using the below snippet and its checking for max 4000 characters, but I am still figuring out how to ignore the **line break**  during the count check.

```
<xsd:simpleType name="TextType">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:minLength value="0"/>
        <xsd:maxLength value="4000"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You need XSD 1.1 (or Schematron) for this kind of thing. It's then easy:

```
<xs:assert test="string-length(translate(., '&#xa;', '')) le 4000"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, Michael again for the hint, Also can you please attach some links to the documentation of this Schematron?

Comment: You can google it as easily as I can.

Comment: Okay also among XSD1.1 and Schematron which will be the preferred approach ? As I currently use XSD1.0.

Comment: Schematron is more powerful but it's a bigger disruption to your current workflow.